# opencv read text in image c#(visual studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi everybody I wrote a code for text detection with opencv But I have got a mistake My code cant entire the forecah Here is my code

```
 public int FindWrite()
    {
       // aimg = new IplImage(img.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1);
        IplImage labelImage = new IplImage(img.Size, CvBlobLib.DepthLabel, 1);
        labelImage = new IplImage(img.Size, BitDepth.U8,1);
        blob = new CvBlobs();
        text.Clear();
      CvBlobLib.Label(labelImage,blob);

        CvBlobLib.FilterByArea(blob, 600, 10000);
        IplImage imgtemp = img.Clone(); 
     //  CvBlobLib.RenderBlobs(blob, img, imgtemp, RenderBlobsMode.BoundingBox | RenderBlobsMode.Angle);
      //  CvBlobLib.RenderBlobs(blob,img, imgtemp, RenderBlobsMode.BoundingBox | RenderBlobsMode.Angle);
        CvBlobLib.RenderBlobs(blob,labelImage, imgtemp, RenderBlobsMode.BoundingBox | RenderBlobsMode.Angle);
       // CvBlobLib.RenderBlobs(blob, labelImage, imgtemp, RenderBlobsMode.BoundingBox | RenderBlobsMode.Angle);
        foreach (var item in blob)
        {

            item.Value.SetImageRoiToBlob(bimg);
            // ratio values of plate between 3.5 and 5.4 
            double ratio = (double)item.Value.Rect.Width / item.Value.Rect.Height;
            double angle = (double)item.Value.Angle();
            if (ratio > 3.5 && ratio < 5.4 && angle > -15 && angle < 15)
            {

                IplImage texttemp = new IplImage(new CvSize(140, 27), bimg.Depth, bimg.NChannels);
                Cv.Resize(bimg, texttemp);

                text.Add(texttemp);
                img.Rectangle(item.Value.Rect, new CvScalar(0, 0, 255), 2, LineType.Link4);
            }
        }

        img.ResetROI();
        return text.Count;

    }
```

thanks your advance

Comment: What happens when you debug it?

Comment: code is going  foreach (var item in blob) but not going to inside

Comment: I wrote class library this project and ı create second project in order to test  with windows form  if you wish I send to my test project's code

Comment: You are labeling `labelImage`, which is empty. So you don't find any blob and don't enter in the loop. Are you sure you don't want to do: `CvBlobLib.Label(img, blob);`

Comment: it is not releated to it So I closed this sentences and is is happen but I dont understand to it why